# How to show relationships of the component containing the interface definition when using ball/socket notation in a UML Component Diagram?

Tags: architecture, uml, diagrams, component, relationships

I recently found out that I have probably been using ball/socket notation in a wrong way all the time. Now I am confused by the different ways of drawing interface relationships in two regards (I think the answers to these are closely related):

1)

Given this small diagram:

[image: FooInterfaceExample]

I can create three components in a higher abstraction diagram each containing one of the pieces (and others) from the above diagram and the same relationship connectors.

However if I use the ball/socket notation, the Foo interface *is* the ball/socket or in other words it's no longer shown where this interface is defined:

[image: BallSocket Example]

How can I show the relationship of `iDefineFoo` component which contains the `Foo` interface definition? Should it always be hidden

2)

Up unitl now I misused the ball notation (provided interface) to show that a component provides the interface definition itself instead of the *realization* of it. So for a component `A` containing the public interfaces for an API I want to show that another component `B` depends on this component `A`. Is the only feasable way to use a simple `dependency` connector? Or how would I show that the dependency is bound to an interface which is inside the component `A`?

I know it's no longer a single question but am I completely wrong and should anyway *always* model the public API and the implementation in the same component?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The goal of a [component](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/component.html) diagram is not the same than a class diagram. Nor is it an alternative to [package diagrams](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/examples/java-servlet-25-api-package-diagram-example.html?context=pkg-examples).

The focus of component diagrams is on self-standing, replaceable components, and how these can be assembled to make more complex systems.

1) The ball/socket representation is about interfaces [provided/required](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/component.html#provided-interface).  So  `FooImpl` would be a component that provides the `Foo` interface  (ball), whereas `Consumer` would require the `Foo` interface (socket).

`Foo` itself is not a component:  the interface is useless without an implementation, so it's not self-standing. The interface is not either replaceable: if you replace it with another interface, it no longer fulfil the expected contract.  So there is no need to have an hypothetical `iDefineFoo` component.

2) The second part of your question seems related to implementation technology. In  UML, an interface is not included in a component.  It's either provided/realized or consumed/required by the component.

All the classes and interfaces required to make a component could be grouped in a package.  A [package diagram](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/examples/java-servlet-25-api-package-diagram-example.html?context=pkg-examples) could better show the interdependence betwen language "components".   Packages are about grouping related modelling elements and their dependencies.  It can be a logical grouping (e.g. layers) or a more tangible grouping (e.g source files, packages, or modelling responsibilities).

If you have a set of classes making one component, and these classes use in a way or another an interface that was initially defined for another component, then you would typically show this with a dependency between two packages, each corresponding to a component.